# Mysql : Fill and update column from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns : `title` and `path`.

I need to fill in the `path` column from `title` column, and remove special characters and spaces from `path`.

```
+------------------+--------------------+
|     title        |        path        |
+------------------+--------------------+
|   Example Title  |   example_title    |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

My script :

```
UPDATE table_name  
SET table_name.path = (  
SELECT table_name.title  
FROM table_name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`.  Something like this:

```
update table_name
    set path = regexp_replace(title, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '');
```

The list of characters in the square braces are the characters that you want to keep.  If you wanted to list the characters to remove, you could use the quite similar:

```
    set path = regexp_replace(title, '[ !.?]', '');
```

I would recommend trying this out in a `select` first.